# How to refresh a grid view(with adapter) keeping the scroll position same?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am developing an application which has a drop down for selecting minimum and maximum age.
I want a spinner to display "Min Age: xx" as the default text for the spinner. Please note that I don't want "Min Age: xx" as the 1st or the last item in the drop down. I want it to be displayed along with the last selected item. For e.g. if I select age 15, the spinner text should display Min Age: 15 and the list below.

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: Could you grab the current position of the spinner, update it, and then set the position just after the spinner is updated?

Comment: I want a default text "Min Age" before every selected item. I cannot add a picture unfortunately as I do not have the required permissions...but I want something like this (please see below step 3): http://www.leawo.org/tutorial/how-to-transfer-music-from-iphone-to-iphone.html